# Minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n \max(|x_i - x|, |y_i - y|)$ - Sum of Max of Absolute Values

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose there are $n$ points $(x_i, y_i)$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Please find another point $(x, y)$ to minimize function:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \max(|x_i - x|, |y_i - y|)$$

Comment: Looks like a small linear program.  It's a guess, but I think the median of $x_i$ and $y_i$ will minimize (but solution is probably not unique in general).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the equivalent linear program

$$\min_{t,x,y} \sum_{i=1}^n t_i\\
\text{subject to } -t_i\leq x-x_i\leq t_i\\
-t_i\leq y-y_i\leq t_i, \text{for }i=1,\dots,n.$$

Comment: very clever approach :), but it is possible to find out the answer in O(n) time? I mean it is possible to get the answer in seconds with a compute even n = 100000? PS, I don't know how to use equivalent linear program till now :-)

Comment: Given that it is a particular linear program you might be able to solve it faster than a generic linear programming algorithm does, but I'm not sure if you can achieve $O(n)$ complexity. I don't know any fast algorithm off the top of my head, though.