# Minimization values for a function

Tags: statistics, optimization

I have got function - non linear(I thk), and a set of variable

`S=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...]`.

The objective is to find the value for `x` and `y` such that

`sum of( max(|x-xi|,|y-yi|) for each (xi,yi) element of S is minimized and | | represents absolute value`.

Is there any algorithm I can code myself to find the solution i.e x and y.

```
eg : S=[(1,4),(2,3),(0,1),(1,1)]

for x=1.5 and y=2.5(and some other values as well) the function gives the minimum value : 5
max(|1.5-1|,|2.5-4|)=1.5
max(|1.5-2|,|2.5-3|)=0.5
max(|1.5-0|,|2.5-1|)=1.5
max(|1.5-1|,|2.5-1|)=1.5
sum:5.0
```

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445862/minimizing-sum-i-1n-maxx-i-x-y-i-y

Comment: @p.s.I am not very good in maths. can somebody please tell some more details about ti in the link so that I can code a program? how it can be obtained?

Comment: @p.s. Also I don't need x,y. The minimized sum will be enough. Is there any algorithm which can find the minimized sum  in less time?